# How to use onActivityResult method from a non-activity class to get the resuts

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a class extends CursorAdapter so I use `((Activity) context).startActivityForResult`. But how can I use onActivityResult? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can you `observer` pattern.

```
public interface ActivityObserver {
    void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private List<ActivityObserver> observers = new ArrayList<ActivityObserver>();

    public void attach(ActivityObserver observer){
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void detach(ActivityObserver observer){
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        for (ActivityObserver observer : observers) {
            observer.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course here you need to implement `ActivityObserver` in your adapter and attach it.

Nevertheless, consider to use [Androjeta](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/observer.html) framework (maintained by me). It comes with a number of features including `Observer` which you can use in your case:

```
public class OnActivityResultEvent {
    int requestCode;
    int resultCode;
    Intent data;

    public OnActivityResultEvent(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Subject
    Observers<OnActivityResultEvent> observers;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        observers.notify(new OnActivityResultEvent(requestCode, resultCode, data));
    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    @Observe(MyActivity.class)
    void onActivityResultEvent(OnActivityResultEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Please, follow the link for details.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onActivityResult()` in your activity.

See: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

If you want other means of notifications, try out [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), if both sender and receiver are your own code.

If you depend on external code or app, you will have to use the activity-way and build around that.